# How to avoid math domain error when we have sqrt

Tags: python, for-loop, math, sqrt

I wrote the following code, after printing about 10 outputs it gets error

```
return 1/sqrt(Om*(1+z)**3+omg0*(1+z)**6+(1-Om-omg0))
ValueError: math domain error
```

**the three first functions are correct and work well in other programs** please do not be sensitive about their structures, I think the problem is in `for-loop` and choosing some values which cannot satisfy the condition of `sqrt`. Could I add some lines to tell Python avoid numbers which lead to `math domain error`? If yes, How should I do that? I mean passing the step which leads to negative value under `sqrt`?

`Cov` is a `31*31` mtrix, `xx[n]` is a list of 31 numbers.

```
def ant(z,Om,w):
    return 1/sqrt(Om*(1+z)**3+w*(1+z)**6+(1-Om-w))

def dl(n,Om,w,M):  
    q=quad(ant,0,xx[n],args=(Om,w))[0]
    h=5*log10((1+xx[n])*q)
    fn=(yy[n]-M-h)                  
    return fn

def c(Om,w,M):
    f_list = []
    for i in range(31):  # the value '2' reflects matrix size
        f_list.append(dl(i,Om,w,M))
    A=[f_list]
    B=[[f] for f in f_list]
    C=np.dot(A,Cov)
    D=np.dot(C,B)
    F=np.linalg.det(D)*0.000001
    return F

N=100
for i in range (1,N):
    R3=np.random.uniform(0,1)

    Omn[i]=Omo[i-1]+0.05*np.random.normal()
    wn[i]=wo[i-1]+0.05*np.random.normal()
    Mn[i]=Mo[i-1]+0.1*np.random.normal()

    L=exp(-0.5*(c(Omn[i],wn[i],Mn[i])-c(Omo[i-1],wo[i-1],Mo[i-1])))

    if L>R3:
        wo[i]=wn[i]

    else:
        wo[i]=wo[i-1]

    print(wo[i])
```

The output is:

```
0.12059556415714912
0.16292726528216397
0.16644447885609648
0.1067588804671105
0.0321446951572128
0.0321446951572128
0.013169965429457382
Traceback (most recent call last):
......
return 1/sqrt(Om*(1+z)**3+omg0*(1+z)**6+(1-Om-omg0))
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: Don't take the square root of negative numbers

Comment: `math.sqrt` doesn't accept negative numbers, which is probably the problem. What do you want `ant` to do when the input is negative? Return a complex number? Return 0?

Comment: If complex values are ok with you and your specific problem use module `cmath` instead of `math`

Comment: @AlexHall  we have random number, some of them lead to negative value under sqrt, How should I tell python to pass them.

Comment: `if value<0: continue`

Comment: What do you mean by 'pass them'? For example you could do nothing when `f_list.append(dl(i,Om,w,M))` fails (because `dl` fails because `ant` fails) and thus end up with `f_list` having fewer elements. Would that work?

Comment: @AlexHall assume, random number `1`, `2`, `3` lead a negative value, I want to jump of them and calculate with another or next value

Comment: @PaulPanzer or use `**0.5`

Comment: So is it fine if `f_list` has fewer than 31 elements? Or do you want to keep increasing `i` until the size is right?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  I think in this case this one can be accepted, Thank you, but for guarantee I need some thing more general. But thank you. What are the differences between `sqrt` and `**0.5`

Comment: @AlexHall no it contains a veeeery big matrix `31*31`, `760*760` and so on

Comment: @Bob ask google, which redirects to StackOverflow :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684948/difference-between-1-2-math-sqrt-and-cmath-sqrt

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks, didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options:

1. Replace `sqrt(...)` with `(...)**0.5`. This will produce complex numbers, which may or may not be acceptable. For example `(-1)**0.5` produces `i` which in Python will appear as `1j` (ignoring floating point errors).
2. Catch errors and move on. Since you probably want to catch the errors higher up, I recommend translating the `ValueError` from `sqrt` into a custom error:

```
class SqrtError(ValueError):
    pass

def ant(z, Om, w):
    val = Om * (1 + z) ** 3 + w * (1 + z) ** 6 + (1 - Om - w)
    try:
        sq = sqrt(val)
    except ValueError:
        raise SqrtError
    return 1 / sq
```

Then it sounds like you want to keep trying new random numbers until you get one that works, which could be done like so:

```
for i in range(1, N):
    R3 = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    while True:

        Omn[i] = Omo[i - 1] + 0.05 * np.random.normal()
        wn[i] = wo[i - 1] + 0.05 * np.random.normal()
        Mn[i] = Mo[i - 1] + 0.1 * np.random.normal()

        try:
            L = exp(-0.5 * (c(Omn[i], wn[i], Mn[i]) - c(Omo[i - 1], wo[i - 1], Mo[i - 1])))
        except SqrtError:
            continue
        else:
            break

    if L > R3:
        wo[i] = wn[i]

    else:
        wo[i] = wo[i - 1]
```

Comment: 3 questions: `1` you mean using `**0.5` lead to wrong answer? `2` the first box jump of the error? `3` the second box, I am not sure that does what I want. my code are saying: calculate `L` if it is bigger than a random number accept new values but if it is smaller than that random number choose the value of previous step.

Comment: the first box works well, but speed of calculating goes down.

Comment: @Bob `1` we don't know what the right or wrong answer is. It's not clear what you want to do, we're all guessing. I don't know if putting complex numbers in your code will do the wrong thing. `2` the first box doesn't change much, it just means that in the second box I can write `except SqrtError` instead of the more general `except ValueError` which might catch things I don't want it to (like errors from `log10`). `3` I've edited the second box to clarify and only generate `R3` once.

Comment: If you don't understand the meaning of `try/except/raise/else/while True/continue/break` please go read carefully about them.

Comment: the first box after printing some output gets this error:`File "C:\.......py", line 68, in ant
    raise SqrtError
SqrtError`

Comment: The first box is useless without the second box. It doesn't sound like you understand at all the constructs that I'm using. Please go read about them, that is essential to solving your problem and an important part of learning to code.

Comment: No man, I got it entirely. But after too many errors my mind is blowing up. I will read your answer in couple of mins later. sorry for this questions.

Comment: It sounds correct, the only problem which I run into it, is, my loop is `N=100` but the out put are 37. maybe 63 numbers lead the sqrt to negative value!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to find the square root of a negative number.

This is not allowed with real-valued numbers (for obvious mathematical reasons), so your best bet is to use a try/except block:

```
def ant(z,Om,w):
    try:
        return 1/sqrt(Om*(1+z)**3+omg0*(1+z)**6+(1-Om-omg0))
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Comment: should I write this block you wrote under `def name():`?

Comment: Hard to say... I don't see where this function is even being used.  If you posted where `ant` is being called I could advise

Comment: `ant` is used in the second function `dl(n,Om,w,M): ` in the line of `q=quad(ant,0,xx[n],args=(Om,w))[0]`

Comment: This code is difficult to read for formatting reasons.  What I can see is you're using `np.random.normal()` to generate gaussian noise.  This is the source of your negative numbers, and this is why you're getting negative square roots.

Comment: yes my friend, exactly, because of this, I need something to jump of numbers which lead to negative value. If your recommended code is correct how should I use it under a `def` block?

Comment: Hard to say.  One way is to just take the absolute value of everything, but I don't know if that's appropriate in your case.  Not sure what your code is supposed to do.  If that's fine, just add `z = abs(z)` (and the others) under the `def ant` you have now.  Again, not sure if that's appropriate since I don't know what your code is supposed to do

Comment: Ok thank you, but my code in the third function is calculating the multiplication of 3 matrixes, the items of these 3 matrixes are calculating in second function, and second function which is a integration calls another function which is the first function. I need a code line which I don't know how, to tell Python, ok, you are checking `if` and` loop` but please check and jump of those numbers which leads the sqrt in the first def a negative value. in the comments a user told me to use `**0.5`